# Is there an alternative to the std::string substring?

Tags: c++, string

Given a string `s = "RADILAMIA"` I want to take all the substrings of length 4 (or something else).

If `len == 4` then the substrings are: "RADI","ADIL","DILA","ILAM","LAMI","AMIA". It seems easy to do that by using the `std::string substr` method:

```
vector<string> allSubstr(string s,int len) {
    vector<string>ans;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.size()-len;i++) {
        ans.push_back(s.substr(i,len));
    }
    return ans;
}
```

`substr`'s time complexity is unspecified, but generally linear against the length of the substring.

Can I do this without `std::string substr`. Any substring and the previous substring differ in only one letter. Is there any better way to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: What is the purpose of `temp` here? Also, why the condition if for loop is `s.size()-len`? Can you explain a bit more? Your question says substring of length `4` but you have calculated substrings of length `10`.

Comment: You pass `s` by value, so the only way you are going to be able to return a bunch of substrings is to copy them into `ans`. `s` will go out of scope. To make this faster, we'd need to see the code that calls this. If you made `s` a `const&`, then you could push pairs of string iterators into ans, and use them as ranges of the string.

Comment: Do you need actual strings? In that case, there isn't a better solution (complexity wise), because you always have to copy those 4 characters. An alternative would be only to store string views (start and length of each substring). Implementation wise you can tweak the code a bit - in particular `temp` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Shubham The loop is `s.size() - len` because he wants it to end with `"AMIA"`, not `"AMIA", "MIA", "IA", "A", ""`

Comment: is it possible to run the program in O(N) time complexity where N is the string length?

Comment: @MikeMB  Yes i need actual substrings but i observe that the character difference of every consecutive substring only one because previous substring's first character will be removed and only one new character append in current substring. If i store the first substring  like "RADI" then i can get next substring from first only remove 'R' and add 'L' in last.i think it's the sliding window technique.Can i implement this technique in this problem?

Comment: @Atif You *assert* that you actually need copies of the input. What you probably need is a pair of iterators that increment across the input, where the second iterator is `len` characters ahead of the first iterator. Again, we would need to see the usage of this function's result to suggest a real improvement. dalle's answer is the closest you can get to the iterator pair trick without knowing what is going on in the caller.

Comment: @Alf if you need multiple independent strings it doesn't matter how they are related, because you always have to copy all 4 characters into the new string. All you can do is try to minimize the scaffolding around it.

Comment: @Atif - "is it possible to run the program in O(N) time complexity where N is the string length? " The best you can hope is O(N*len) because you want the substrings in a vector and each copy of the substring will result in `len` characters being copied anyway.

Comment: @doug65536 in reality a pair of iterators will be as big, if not bigger than a copied string (at least on a 64 bit machine)

Comment: @RichardHodges As big? Would a pair of iterators call malloc repeatedly? Would a pair of iterators copy the data redundantly into an allocated (vector) block holding bunch of separate allocated (string) blocks?

Comment: @doug65536 a pair of iterators on a 64-bit machine is 16 bytes. A string less that ~20 bytes long won't allocate any memory because of SSO (the string class re-purposes its internal memory when it detects that it is shorter than this threshold). Copying a small string in c++ is of the same order of complexity and timing as manipulating the iterators. It's why we should always favour simple code. The library implementors have already thought about our petty performance concerns.

Comment: @Richard: Right. Although from the Question it is not  clear if the strings in the real applications are also that short. Also the actual code the compiler has to optimize when working with strings is more complex (branchy) when working with strings.

Comment: @MikeMB first point I accept. Second is not necessarily the case. an implementor could reasonably instruct the cpu to predict that short strings are the common case (since for long strings misprediction is less of an issue). In reality of course, `std::string` is a template, so the optimiser can see through all local operations. Any decision-based cost for non-mutating algorithms will be paid at most once per discrete code evaluation context. In this particular case, the cost need never be paid since the short string code path can be selected at compile time.

Comment: @Richard: I didn't say the resulting binary code was more complex (although it was in my test). Just that the optimizer has to do more work, which might lead to different inlining decisions etc.. A view/pair of pointers is just a simple, trivially copyable and destructible datastructure and the pointers don't even get dereferenced in that function. It would be pretty hard for a SSO to beat that.

Comment: @MikeMB understood. I accept that we can save a few instructions by using an iterator pair or string_view. Whether the extra logic complexity and dangling dependencies are worth it is another matter.

Comment: @Richard: Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There can be millions of different approaches. Here is my algorithm.

```
vector<string> allSubstr(string s,int len) {

    vector<string>ans;
    ans.reserve(s.size() - len );
    for(size_t i=0;i<=s.size()-len;i++) 
    {
        ans.emplace_back( s.begin() +i, s.begin() + i + len );
    }

    return ans;
}
```

It is tested. I mean it wouldn't matter what you are using but emplace_back above can make a difference since there won't be copy cost. Also you add reserve for more performance.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, what is the time complexity of the `std::rotate`?

Comment: And how is rotating the original string better than just copying from an offset? You are doing additional work, that gains you nothing

Comment: It is linear http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate. And it is even not needed here. I just used it for the beauty of it. "i" and "len" can be manipulated and it can be removed.

Comment: Using rotate makes it `O(n^2)` because it copies n things n times.

Comment: OK I were a bit excited about rotate . I removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do, you still need O(NL) time to write all your substrings into the vector.

The fastest thing would be probably:

```
vector<string> ans(s.size()-len);
for(int i=0;i<=s.size()-len;i++) {
    ans[i] = s.substr(i, len);
}
```

Because `push_back` is slowish, and should generally be avoided if possible.  It is overused.

PS: maybe this code would be even faster:

```
vector<string> ans(s.size()-len);
for(int i=0;i<=s.size()-len;i++) {
    ans[i].append(s.begin()+i, s.begin()+i+len);
}
```

Comment: `vector<string> ans[s.size()-len];` VLAs aren't standard c++.

Comment: Fixed the brackets.

Comment: @dalle - yes, fixed this too.  I made 2 errors in 4 lines, shame on me.

Comment: i observe that the character difference of every consecutive substring only one because previous substring's first character will be removed and only one new character append in current substring. If i store the first substring like "RADI" then i can get next substring from first only remove 'R' and add 'L' in last.i think it's the sliding window technique.Can i implement this technique in this problem?

Comment: @Atif - if you "only" remove R, such a removal takes linear time, so I doubt you gain anything.

Answer (score 1):

[`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17) has a constant time [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr):

```
vector<string_view> allSubstr(const string_view& s, int len) {
    vector<string_view> ans;
    and.reserve(s.size() - len + 1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= s.size() - len; ++i) {
        ans.push_back(s.substr(i, len));
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Just make sure that `s` outlives the return value of the function.

Comment: `const string_view& s` has to become `string_view s`, Probably the safe and standard footprint would be :
`vector<string> & allSubstr( vector<string> & result, string_view s, const size_t len)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use an array of chars instead. For example, you have got your word:

```
char s[] = "RADILAMIA";
```

To deal with all necessary substrings you can use such approach:

```
int substLength = 4;
int length = strlen(s);
char buffer[256];
for (int i = 0; i < length - substLength + 1; i++) {
    strncpy(buffer, s + i, substLength);
    buffer[substLength] = '\0';
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Using the char array you easily can access to the start of any substring by adding the necessary index to the beginning of the array.

Comment: That is not C++. That is C that uses `cout`.

Comment: What is the time complexity of the `strncpy` function again?

Comment: This code works in C++ as well. You are not forbidden of the use of char arrays or `strncpy` in C++. I wrote this code because it works faster than a code using `std::string` object from C++.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to use `strncpy`, instead you can refer to the beginning of your substring within the given string. The complexity of `strncpy` is `O(m)` where `m` is the length of the destination. Read more: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Comment: @Fomalhaut _"... because it works faster than a code using `std::string` object from C++"_ Sure about that? Did you measure?

Comment: You can measure it by yourself or do your own research about it. An example of research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946447/how-much-performance-difference-when-using-string-vs-char-array

Comment: "The complexity of strncpy is O(m) where m is the length of the destination. " So your total complexity is O(N*m), right? How's this different from the solution in the OP with substrings?

Comment: What is `N`? I was asked about the complexity of `strncpy`.

Comment: "What is N?" The length of the original string.

Comment: @Fomalhaut Sorry, but you should post **your** implementation of the same code, but using `std::string`.  Don't link to other code that does something entirely different.

Comment: OP substrings would work slower. But if you are satisfied with their speed, you can use them of course, because they are more convenient to use in other pieces of code.

Comment: Quite frankly, I'd also expect this to be faster (ignoring the `std::cout` and although `strncopy` does more work than needed here). In particular it saves dynamic memory allocations from the `std::vector` (depending on the size also from `std::string`) and doesn't have any temporaries (which the compiler might or might not get rid of in the OP's exmple). **But** you don't return a array of strings, as the OP does, so it isn't really a solution to do the same thing faster.

Answer (score 0):

It pays to revisit the docos

```
// string proto(len);
vector<string> result(s.size()-len, string(len, char(32))); // preallocates the buffers

const char *str=s.c_str();
const char* end=str+s.size()-len;

for(size_t i=0; str<end; str++, i++) {
  result[i].assign(str, len); // likely to result in a simple copy in the preallocated buffer
}
```

The complexity is the same O(len*s.size()) - one can only hope for a smaller proportionality factor.

Answer (score 0):

C is not always faster than C++ but @Fomalhaut was right to post the performant core solution in C. Here is my (C program) complete version, based on his algorithm. Without using strncpy, too.

[Here it is on the godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xsq838).

```
#ifdef __STDC_ALLOC_LIB__
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1
#else
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// array of buffers == a_of_b
typedef struct a_of_b  {
    const unsigned size;
    unsigned count ;
    char ** data   ;
} a_of_b ;

a_of_b a_of_b_make ( const unsigned size_ ) 
{
   return (a_of_b){ .size = size_, .count = 0, .data = calloc(1, sizeof(char * [size_] ) ) } ;
}

a_of_b * a_of_b_append ( a_of_b * self,  const unsigned len_, const char str_[len_] ) 
{
    assert( self->data ) ;
    assert( self->size > self->count ) ;
    self->data[ self->count ] = strndup( str_, len_ ) ;
    self->count += 1;
    return self ;
}

a_of_b * a_of_b_print ( a_of_b * self , const char * fmt_ ) 
{
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < self->count; ++j)
         printf( fmt_ , self->data[j]);
    return self ;
}

a_of_b * a_of_b_free ( a_of_b * self  ) 
{
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < self->count; ++j)
         free( self->data[j]) ;
    free( self->data) ;
    self->count = 0  ;         
    return self ;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
a_of_b breakit ( const unsigned len_, const char input_[len_], const unsigned  substLength )
{
    assert( len_ > 2 ) ;
    assert( substLength > 0 ) ;
    assert( substLength < len_ ) ;

    const unsigned count_of_buffers = len_ - substLength + 1;

    a_of_b rez_ = a_of_b_make( count_of_buffers +1 ) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < count_of_buffers ; i++) {
        a_of_b_append( &rez_, substLength, input_ + i ) ;
    }

   return rez_ ;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static void driver( const char * input_, const unsigned substLength ) 
{
    printf("\n");
    a_of_b substrings = breakit( strlen(input_), input_, substLength );
    a_of_b_print( & substrings , "%s ");
    a_of_b_free( & substrings);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main () { 

    driver( "RADILAMIA", 4) ;
    driver( "RADILAMIA", 3) ;
    driver( "RADILAMIA", 2) ;
    driver( "RADILAMIA", 1) ;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

And the program output is:

```
RADI ADIL DILA ILAM LAMI AMIA 

RAD ADI DIL ILA LAM AMI MIA 

RA AD DI IL LA AM MI IA 

R A D I L A M I A
```

Enjoy.